# How can I access `this` in an event handler?

Tags: javascript, oop, events, this

I have a class which creates a DOM element and has to capture all click events.

Simplified code:

```
function myClass()
{
  this.domElement = document.createElement("canvas");
  this.domElement.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
}
myClass.prototype.handleClick = function(evt)
{
  alert("Clicked!");
  // How to modify `this` object?
}
```

Now I want to modify some attributes and variables of the myClass instance in `handleClick()`. But `this` refers to the canvas object, of course.

**Question:** How can I access `this` of an object in an event handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished via closing over a reference to your instance and using apply to force the scope of a function:

In step 1 I have your example showing how `this` is the element which was clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/GJXpQ/

In step 2 I have an example which stores a reference to your instance in your constructor, then sets an anonymous function as the click handler and calls your click method off the stored reference. http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/GJXpQ/1/ This causes `this` within your click handler to be your instance and will work for you if you do not need access to the element which was clicked.

In step 3 I have stored the same reference, and used an anonymous function, but inside that function I grab the arguments which come into the anon function on click, I add the reference to the instance to those arguments, and I call the click handler in scope of the clicked element and pass the new set of arguments. http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/GJXpQ/2/ Using this methodology, inside the click handler I can access the clicked element via `this`, and the instance of `myClass` via `instance`.

I hope this helps. It can be quite confusing, so ask questions if needed.

Comment: Many thanks for three solutions! I like best solution 2 (good and simple). But for which reason I need to access the original `this`? When I want to have access to the DOM element, I do it by `evt.target`.

Comment: It's just a matter of preference and a matter of how the code is written. If you prefer 2 and use of `evt.target` that's legitimate. But if you were adapting some existing code you could end up in a situation where you needed a different scope, so 3 might work better in that situation.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm writing my own framework, so there aren't any problems regarding this. Answer accepted ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
function myClass() {
  var self = this;

  this.domElement = document.createElement("canvas");
  this.domElement.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
      // use self here
  });
}
```

Since listener is actually a closure, it maintains reference to the variable `self`, which is object you're observing. Actual `this`, as you figured it out, references canvas element.

Another way that'd work, and keep methods seperated:

```
function myClass(){
  var self = this;

  this.domElement = document.createElement("canvas");
  this.domElement.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    myClass.prototype.call(self, evt);
  });
}
myClass.prototype.handleClick = function(evt){
  alert("Clicked!");
  // How to modify `this` object?
}
```

Now this one uses [Function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and assigns what `this` references to.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the example to test the access to 'this': http://jsfiddle.net/StWu9/.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.bind`, which "freezes" the `this` value with a preset one: http://jsfiddle.net/TKAHg/.

`.bind` returns a new function which does the same thing as the original function, but it sets the `this` so that you can rely on it being the value you provided.

Although `.bind` is not available on older browsers, [MDC has a shim for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
// bind 'this' value inside handleClick when clicked
this.domElement.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the example, so the element is clickable: http://jsfiddle.net/TKAHg/1/.
Old browsers are no problem because I use the canvas element. But I need to support Opeara and Safari.