# How to access 'this' in angular 2 event handler?

Tags: angular

In my *Component's* `keydown` event handler, I need to modify a propery of the component via `this`:

```
  canvasKeyHandler (event) {
    console.log('vrscene.canvasKeyHandler: event.keyCode=' + event.keyCode);
    console.log('vrscene.canvasKeyHandler: self.dolly' + this.dolly);

    CameraKeypressEvents.keyHandler(event, this.dolly) // <-- do something with this.dolly
```

But `this.dolly` is set to `undefined`:

```
vrscene.canvasKeyHandler: self.dollyundefined
```

vrscene.html:

```
<div class="container" id ="canvas-container-2">
   <canvas id="vrruntime-view"
           class="camera-keypress-events"
           tabindex="1"
           (keydown)="canvasKeyHandler($event)"
           style="border: 1px solid black;"
           >
   </canvas>
           <!--camera-keypress-events [cubeScene]="cubeScene" -->

</div>
```

vrscene.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import WebGLRenderer = THREE.WebGLRenderer;
import {VRRenderer} from '../vrrenderer/vrrenderer'
import {CameraKeypressEvents} from '../camera-keypress-events/camera-keypress-events'

import Object3D = THREE.Object3D;
import Scene = THREE.Scene;
import PerspectiveCamera = THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
import Mesh = THREE.Mesh;
import VRControls = THREE.VRControls;
import VREffect = THREE.VREffect;

@Component ({
  selector: 'vrscene',
  templateUrl: 'app//vrscene/vrscene.html',
})

@Injectable()
export class VRScene {

  private _scene: Scene;
  camera: PerspectiveCamera;
  dolly: Object3D;
  vrControls: VRControls;
  vrEffect: VREffect;
  webVrManager;
  sphere: Mesh;
  cube: Mesh;
  BaseRotation = new THREE.Quaternion();

  constructor() {}

  //initScene(width: number, height: number, renderer: VRRenderer) {
  init(width: number, height: number, vrRenderer: VRRenderer) {
    console.log('VRScene.init: entered')
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene;

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height);
    this.camera.position.set(0, 1.5, 100);
    this.dolly = new THREE.Object3D();
    this.dolly.position.z = 50;
    this.scene.add(this.dolly);
    //
    this.dolly.add(this.camera);

    this.vrControls = new THREE.VRControls(this.camera);

    this.vrEffect = new THREE.VREffect(vrRenderer.renderer);
    this.vrEffect.setSize(width, height);
    this.webVrManager = new (<any>window).WebVRManager(vrRenderer.renderer, this.vrEffect);
    console.log('VRScene.init: this.webVrManager=' + this.webVrManager);
    this.camera.quaternion.copy(this.BaseRotation);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(25, 25, 25);
    var meshParms = new Object();

    meshParms['color'] = 0xff8000;

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(meshParms);
    //material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(this.cube);

    // draw!
    vrRenderer.canvas.focus();
    //CubeOnPlaneScene.prototype.mainLoop.bind(this)
    // bind the 'this' of the canvasKeyHandler to the definition-time 'this'
    //VRScene.prototype.canvasKeyHandler.bind(this)
  }

  canvasKeyHandler (event, dolly) {
    console.log('vrscene.canvasKeyHandler: event.keyCode=' + event.keyCode);
    //console.log('vrscene.canvasKeyHandler: this.dolly' + this.dolly);
    //console.log('vrscene.

canvasKeyHandler: self.dolly' + this.dolly);
    console.log('vrscene.canvasKeyHandler: dolly' + dolly);

    //CameraKeypressEvents.keyHandler(event, this.dolly)
    //CameraKeypressEvents.keyHandler(event, VRScene.prototype.canvasKeyHandler)
    CameraKeypressEvents.keyHandler(event, dolly)
  }

  doIt() : string {
    return 'hello from VRScene'
  }

  // getters  and setters
  get scene():Scene {
     return this._scene;
  }

  set scene(scene: Scene) {
    if (scene === undefined) throw 'Please supply a scene';
    this._scene = scene;
  }

}
```

Key handler:

```
import {Directive} from 'angular2/core';
import {CubeScene} from '../cube-scene/cube-scene';
import Object3D = THREE.Object3D;
import Vector3 = THREE.Vector3;
import {Base} from '../base/base';
import Quaternion = THREE.Quaternion;


@Directive({
  selector: '[camera-keypress-events]',
  providers: [],
  //host: {},
  host: {
    '(keypress)' : 'onKeypress($event)'
  },

})

export class CameraKeypressEvents {

  constructor() {}

  static CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA = 1.2;
  static CAMERA_ROT_DELTA = 5;

  static keyHandler (event, dolly: Object3D) {
    console.log('CameraKeypressEvents.keyHandler: event.keyCode=' + event.keyCode)
    console.log('CameraKeypressEvents.keyHandler: dolly=' + dolly)   
        switch( event.keyCode) {
      case 'S'.charCodeAt(0):
        console.log('you pressed s');
        //dolly.position.z += CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA;
        dolly.translateZ(this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA);
        console.log('dolly.postion.x=' + dolly.position.x);
      break;

      case 'W'.charCodeAt(0):
        //console.log('you pressed s');
        //this.dolly.position.z -= this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA;
        dolly.translateZ(-this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA);
        //console.log('this.do-ly.postion.x=' + this.dolly.position.x);
      break;

      case 'A'.charCodeAt(0):
        //this.dolly.position.x -= this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA;
        dolly.translateX(-this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA);
      break;

      case 'D'.charCodeAt(0):
        //console.log('you pressed s');
        //this.dolly.position.x += this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA;
        dolly.translateX(this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA);
        //console.log('this.dolly.postion.x=' + this.dolly.position.x);
      break;

      case 'N'.charCodeAt(0):
        //this.dolly.position.y -= this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA;
        dolly.translateY(-this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA);
      break;

      case 'P'.charCodeAt(0):
        //console.log('you pressed s');
        //this.dolly.position.y += this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA;
        //console.log('this.dolly.postion.x=' + this.dolly.position.x);
        dolly.translateY(this.CAMERA_MOVE_DELTA);
      break;

      case 'Q'.charCodeAt(0):
        var tmpQuat = (new THREE.Quaternion()).setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), Base.ONE_DEG * this.CAMERA_ROT_DELTA);
        dolly.quaternion.multiply(tmpQuat);
      break;

      case 'E'.charCodeAt(0):
        var tmpQuat = (new THREE.Quaternion()).setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), Base.ONE_DEG * -this.CAMERA_ROT_DELTA);
        dolly.quaternion.multiply(tmpQuat);
      break;
    };
  }

   onKeypress (event, cubeScene) {
    console.log('CameraKeypressEvents.onKeypress: event.keyCode=' + event.keyCode)
        //event.preventDefault();
    console.log('vtClass.canvasKeyhandler: cubeScene=' + cubeScene);
    console.log(event, event.keyCode, event.keyIdentifier);

    /*
    */
  }
}
```

How do I either:

A) pass the instance on the keyhandler call?

I tried:

```
(keydown)="canvasKeyHandler($event,{{dolly}})"
```

B) Bind the `canvasKeyHandler` method to the compile time `this`?

I tried:

```
// bind the callback 'this' of the canvasKeyHandler to the definition-time 'this'
VRScene.prototype.canvasKeyHandler.bind(this)
```

and

```
  canvasKeyHandler (event) {
    ...
}.bind(this)
```

My apologies if this is an obvious question, but I'm just learning the Angular 2 framework and getting a little overwhelmed at this point. Do I need to do something with @Input?

Many Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the complete code of your component? Thanks!

Comment: Ok,  I passed all the component code.  If you need to see the entire project code, then I might have to do a plunker on that.

Comment: Remove `@Injectable()` from your VRScene component (`@Injectable` is only needed for services that have dependencies).  Posting a "wall of code" often works against you on StackOverflow.   People often won't take the time to read it, whether that is people who can help you, or future readers with similar problems. Make a **minimal** plunker that only shows the issue.  E.g., remove all of those case statements -- show just one, IF it is really need to to demonstrate the problem.  It maybe be easier for you to just paste everything, but, as I said, you'll get less help.

Comment: Removing @Injectable did not help.  Actually, the official doc [recommends you add @injectable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) to every service, even those that do not have depenencies.  And thank you for the feedback on the optimal amount of code to include.  As it turns out, this particular problem would have needed a full blown plunker in order for anyone to fix it as the problem was kind of subtle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a real object lesson in the subtleties of DI for me.

Basically, this problem can be attributed to *user error*.  There weren't any smoking gun issues with angular2 or typescript not working properly.  My main problem was using 'init' methods to initialize my component instead of doing it in the constructor.  I was doing this because I wanted late binding of properties that I felt may not be known until run time.  This is fine, but it appears the injector was not driving my init code (or maybe it was and the properties just weren't defined at the time).  There was also the factor of having a component that was sub-classing a parent  using inheritance, instead of dependency injection.   It looks like the injector might have been only driving the parent class's constructor and not the child's, although I can't definitively say this was the case as I had several issues going on.

I'm in the process of refactoring my code to use DI only, and to put all initialization in the constructors, and overall just being a little tighter about controlling the DI process.

The main takeaway for anyone having a similar problem is to realize that there are three potential contexts in which you component may exist or be created: compile-time, injection-time, and run-time. There may even be *load-time*, but I'm assuming this is the same as *injection-time*.  "Normally", they're all the same and you don't have to distinguish between them, but just keep in mind if you're doing *late dynamic initialization*, and/or using inheritance instead of DI, that the injected component may not be in quite the state you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

```
(keydown)="canvasKeyHandler($event,{{dolly}})"
```

should be

```
(keydown)="canvasKeyHandler($event,dolly)"
```

I don't know if this actually fixes your problem (don't really understand what the issue is)

Comment: Nope.  It still says dolly is undefined in the event handler.

Comment: I can't make any sense of your code fragments. For example how they are connected. What about creating a Plunker that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It's similar [to this plain old javascript question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696672/how-can-i-access-this-in-an-event-handler), but in the context of angular 2.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` corresponds to the instance of your component within the event handler (`canvasKeyHandler`). I think that using the following to configure the handler for the `keydown` event is enough:

```
(keydown)="canvasKeyHandler($event)"
```

I saw that you initialize the `dolly` property within the `init` method. But I can't see where this method is called. Perhaps it's the reason of your problem...

Comment: Yes, I think you're on the right track here.  However, one thing I did not mention (because I didn't think it was relevant..doh) is that my component is in an inheritance relationship.  I am currently trying to characterize the situation, but it definitely appears that angular 2 event handlers are returning a `this` that is not the same as the expected `this` e.g some attributes are there and others not, and parent/child info is missing depending on the context etc.  But your suggestion was helpful because it gave me confidence that this handler _should_ work and to focus on why.